# Automating Application Installations in Batch

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, automation

I am trying to write a Script that will install our remote app applications automatically. Here is what I have so far:

```
REM Install Remote Icons
@Echo On
pushd "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\"
start msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\ExercisePro.msi" /qn
start msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Excel.msi" /qn
start msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Word.msi" /qn
start msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Outlook.msi" /qn
start msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Allscripts EHR.msi" /qn
start msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Allscripts PM.msi" /qn
start msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\MModal Allscripts EHR.msi" /qn
popd

mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Icons

copy C:\Users\%USERNAME%\%APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\Installer   C:\Icons

pushd "\\Servername.com\M Modal\Fluency.Direct.9.1.65.7.6.4.v7\fd.client\install_silent.bat"
popd

copy \\Servername.com\Private IT\PC_Shortcuts  \\%COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME%\Public\Desktop

pause
```

So far the script is not working as I intended it. I want it to install the applications then I want it to make a directory called C:\Icons and copy the app data over to that folder so I can delete the appdata entries that it makes and those entries take the user profile longer to login. Also I have a folder on the server that I want to copy to the local desktop that has all of the internet shortcuts we use. This is also not working correctly :(

Comment: Hi does it matter if the script is in Powershell or does it need to be in a batch file?

Comment: There are many free remote install software solutions that would be more full featured, like PDQ Deploy, that would make this easier. Are you expecting this to run in user context? How are you running this? You don't really explain what is not working

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

Also do you really need all the pushd and popd if you are providing the full location of the sources you are copying. If you are executing a file, and calling it by it's full Universal Naming Convention (i.e. C:\Folder\Test.txt) then you don't need to change your current directory to C:\Folder, you can run that file from anywhere within the computers file system, as you are providing the full file location.

If you want to run the file by only providing the filename, or a partial address to the file, you would then need to change to the directory the file is residing in, or provide the location to the director from where you are located. (i.e. if you are in C:\Folder1 and the file resides in C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File.txt you would need to use the following address .\Folder2\Folder3\File.txt as you are already located in C:\Folder1 and the .\ acts as a placeholder\variable for the current directory you are sitting in).

```
REM Install Remote Icons
@Echo On

msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\ExercisePro.msi" /qn /norestart
msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Excel.msi" /qn /norestart
msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Word.msi" /qn /norestart
msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Outlook.msi" /qn /norestart
msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Allscripts EHR.msi" /qn /norestart
msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\Allscripts PM.msi" /qn /norestart
msiexec /i "\\Servername.com\it\RDP\Installers\MModal Allscripts EHR.msi" /qn /norestart

Call "\\Servername.com\M Modal\Fluency.Direct.9.1.65.7.6.4.v7\fd.client\install_silent.bat"

mkdir C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Icons

copy C:\Users\%USERNAME%\%APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\Installer\*.* C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Icons /Y

copy \\Servername.com\Private IT\PC_Shortcuts\*.* \\%COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME%\Public\Desktop /Y

pause
```

**NOTE:** *I have added in the /norestart to ensure that your device doesn't restart after any of the installations, which would then in turn kill the installation script.*

Comment: Thank You! But I don't think it is working correctly. It is not calling the Batch file inside of the M*Modal folder and it is also not installing the applications. Is my spacing wrong as far as the copy commands go ?

Comment: Hi, sorry I left out the batch file, I've added that in now. I noticed you were copying the icons to C:\Icons as well, after creating the icons in the C:\users\%USERNAME%\Icons folder so I've altered that, but obviously alter it back if it's not where you intended them to go. For the msi's not installing, can you tell me if there's an error, or if anything pops up on your screen. Keep in mind they have the /q switch on the end, so they'll be installing silently. If you just want a loading window and nothing else, you can change the /qn to a /passive and then you can see whats happening.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. Most of the time the window disappears it will start and then it will go away and you won't see anything. I figured I needed to call the batch file on the M*Modal installation but wasn't sure. Start didn't seem to be working correctly. I will change to a /passive and test ! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I had M Modal not M*Modal, so yes you'll need to change that. I'm off to bed now but let me know how it goes and I'll help you out if you still need a hand when I wake up.

Comment: Hey, how did you go with your installation.

Comment: The call command worked fine for me but the msiexec commands did not install the applications correctly. It was like it would install one and then the next time I try to run it would install another one but it wouldn't install all of them. The syntax is super picky and half the time it will install some but not all.

Comment: Create a folder in your C drive called logs, then on the end of each msiexec command add /L C:\Logs\{MSIName}.txt where {MSIName}.txt is a unique name for each log file, this will output a log file into the C:\Logs folder for each one and should tell you the error code, which you can look up online and get some more info, the log may even tell you what's wrong. Let me know how you go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell remoting for this tasks. Check `invoke-command` with the `-ComputerName` parameter for remote actions. With Powershell version 5 `Copy-Item` supports `FromSession ToSession` parameters to copy files  remotely. You can run msiexec via `Start-Process`.